# How to get button at the bottom of the screen independent of middle tab content?

Tags: android, listview, button, tabs, footer

I have set of buttons at the bottom of screen below listview. But i am unable to get it exactly in the bottom because i am defining height of listview (tabcontent) which is in middle, if i don't predefine height of tabcontent it would overlay button and if i define it would mess up button position in different screen resolutions. So how can i actually achieve buttons at the bottom of screen independent of middle tab content it ? Below is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/formLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="0dp">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="465dip"
                android:layout_above="@+id/btnSend"
                android:layout_below="@+id/separator" >

                <!-- Scrollview for message data -->

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/formTab"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/formLayout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="5dip" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabcontent"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/messages"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Messages"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/history"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="History"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/support"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Support"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LinearLayout with buttons is inside another LinearLayout.

All you have to do is to change your root layout to RelativeLayout then the parameter `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` of your LinearLayout with buttons will work.

Also you should make the root RelativeLayout to fill the parent.

The whole layout will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/formLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="465dip"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_below="@+id/separator" >

            <!-- Scrollview for message data -->

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/formTab"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/formLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="5dip" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabcontent"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/messages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Messages"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/history"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="History"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/support"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Support"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are making no mistake ? Coz if i do the way u suggested listview will still go in the back of button

Comment: If you have the list in any of your tabs then it's a problem. But you can avoid overlapping by setting bottom padding for the layout in the tab. E.g. set bottom padding for the ScrollView

Comment: Yes there is ListView in tabcontent. Let me try bottom padding.

Comment: Do you really need a ListView? I suggest to replace it with ScrollView if it's possible. ScrollView has much less problems with placing elements below it. And what is the layout description for the ListView you try to place into the tab?

Comment: Actually its a static listview...yes i guess required for requirement. But even if we replace with scroll view what placeholder will u put instead of listview. I don't think so text view is suitable thing for this case. However i tried bottomPadding for scrollView looks like it will work till some extent...if not i guess will have to change wholeee layout :(  I appreciate your help on it

Comment: I guess your suggestion for adding bottomPadding for ScrollView worked fine...Testing on many resolutions and it is showing positive results. Thanks